# CamanJS: Dynamically load an image onto canvas

Tags: javascript, html, camanjs

Using CamanJS, how can I dynamically load an image onto the canvas?

All I have is the base64 encoding of a PNG.

I find the API documentation of CamanJS to be anything but complete. It doesn't even have the this.save() function documented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to load required image first. After that pass the image object to camanjs function as below.

```
var myimage = new Image();
    myimage.onload = function() {
          $('#myImageDiv').html('<img id="my-image" src='+myimage.src+' />');
          Caman('#my-image', function () {
                 this.brightness(10);
                 this.contrast(30);
                 this.sepia(60);
                 this.saturation(-30);
                 this.render();
          });
    }
    myimage.src = 'images/myimage.jpg';
```